# Problem of obtaining a particle trajectory in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

Due to the Uncertainty Principle, the position and the velocity of a particle cannot be specified simultaneously with infinite accuracy for a quantum particle. Therefore, it does not have a trajectory because the adequate initial conditions required for solving Newton's equation $m\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}=\vec F$ are not available. However, instead of specifying the position and velocity at $t=0$, we can try to solve Newton's equation by measuring the positions $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ at two different instants of time $t_1$ and $t_2$ and giving those as the inputs to the differential equation, we can solve Newton's equation to get a trajectory. Classically, we can do this.

What is the reason that this prescription fails to give a trajectory in quantum mechanics? Is it because of the fact that we cannot make a measurement of the position at the next instant $t_2$, without disturbing the state of the system?

Comment: You'll also need velocities $v_1,v_2$ at these same time moments, which is forbidden to measure accurately due to uncertainty principle (because you have already measured positions $r_1,r_2$)